Doesn't counting hole and electron current lead to double-counting of actual current?
Consider two adjacent silicon atoms in a crystal, where the right nuclei is actually a hole. An electron transfers from the one on the left to the right. If we were to count both hole current and electron current, one would say that one electron moved from left to right and also that one hole moved from right to left, which leads to actually count two instances of equivalent things, as actually only one electron moved from left to right, which leads to one negative electron charge to move from left to right in time t, but our method leads us to really count two net negative electron charges to move left to right.

@PatoGalmarini I do not think you are correct. From my understanding, the hole is the net positive character which occurs due to the absence of equal number of electrons to neutralize the charge of the nucleus. Initially the absence was in the right atom, which ended up going to the left atom.

@Blank you might be right, I erased my comment

The mathematics of this is very clearly described in chapter 12 and 13 of the book by Ashcroft and Mermin

Your mistake here is the assumption that both electron and hole are counted in the same band. If this assumption were correct, then indeed, we'd have counted the carriers twice.
But actually, electron current is the current of free electrons in the conduction band, while hole current is the current of free holes in the valence band. The bound holes in the conduction band and electrons in the valence band are never counted as taking part in conduction (unless we discard the notion of a hole and try to describe valence band conduction in terms of the bound electrons).

Current is measured through a surface. If, in one unit time, a free electron passes through the surface and then recombines with a hole, the current is one unit charge per unit time. If, in one unit time, a hole passes through the surface and then recombines with a free electron, that is a current of one unit charge per unit time. If, in one unit time, a free electron and a hole both pass through a surface traveling in opposite directions, and then each recombines with some other hole and free electron, then the current is two unit charges per unit time.

An electron transfers from the one on the left to the right. If we were to count both hole current and electron current, one would say that one electron moved from left to right and also that one hole moved from right to left, which leads to actually count two instances of equivalent things, as actually only one electron moved from left to right, which leads to one negative electron charge to move from left to right in time t, but our method leads us to really count two net negative electron charges to move left to right.

In this scenario, the free electron and hole are separated. Assume a surface between them. If the free electron and hole recombined, then either the free electron passed through the surface, and the hole did not, or the hole passed through the surface and the free electron did not. Or they both reached the surface, and neither left because they recombined. If they met and recombined at the surface, neither "passed through", we can deal with that situation either by a) moving the surface so that only one passed through, or b) by doing some more complicated bookkeeping.
The more complicated bookkeeping might be as follows. We could count reaching the surface and leaving the surface  as each being "half" a unit charge through the surface. Those that reach the surface and pass through would then be counted as one unit of charge passing through. Those that reach the surface but then reverse direction would be counted as 0 units of charge passing through, and those that reach the surface but didn't leave in either direction as a half unit of charge "passing through". Then when a free electron reaches the surface, but does not leave it, and a hole, traveling in the opposite direction also reaches the surface but doesn't leave it, we would count that as one unit of charge passing through. Thus, if a free electron and a hole recombine on the surface, we neither double count, nor lose a count.

A simple way is to think of a moving hole as electrons filling the vacancy. Then we actually have two electrons moving - the one that previously occupied the hole (but is now in the conduction band), and the one which jumps into the hole (leaving another hole behind):

(image source)

The picture and your description are far too simplistic, in complete disconnect with one another, and indeed not illustrative of the actual process in creating electrons and holes that carry current.

@JeffreyJWeimer any physical model is just an approximation to reality - its value is in capturing the essential. I think for the purposes of this question this is quite enough. Developing here theory of holes as fermionic quasiparticles would be the proverbial hammering nails with a microscope.

After a moment (or two), I better respect your picture.

@JeffreyJWeimer please avoid drastic editing of answers) questions without consulting the author.

Pardon ... I expected authors had the privilege to agree or disagree with edits. Consulting with authors in advance is new to me. My mistake for overstepping. I stand corrected.

The problem with the animation is that a state moves the same whether filled or empty. Its much more like a conveyor belt than this hopping depiction. The animation breaks down if you try to explain the semiconductor Hall effect, for example.

@Matt a state moves the same whether filled or empty - you mean a state in position or momentum representation? And by the state - do you mean the eigenvalue of a Hamiltonian, which is an unmeasurable mathematical object?

I mean the Bloch states that describe the apparent behavior of electron and hole quasiparticles in semiconductors. The states from which the concept of a hole arises.

@Matt the animation is in the position representation - you can think of Wannier states, for example. However, the point is that the concept of a hole is much more fundamental - grounded in charge conservation, rather than details of semiconductor theory. Even if quantum theory and band theory were wrong, holes would still exist.


If we were to count both hole current and electron current, one would say that one electron moved from left to right and also that one hole moved from right to left, which leads to actually count two instances of equivalent things

Yes. If we were to count a given charge carrier as both a hole current and an electron current then we would double count. We don’t do that.
We do a Hall type measurement to determine the sign of the charge carriers. If they are positive then it is a hole current and if they are negative then it is an electron current. There is no double counting because the type of current carrier is known from experiments.
It is of course possible to have both positive and negative charge carriers, which is also determined with Hall measurements. Each type is its own and not double-counted as the other.

I am not aware of the hall type measurement. Could you explain or lead to a source?

Wikipedia does a pretty good job: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect#Theory
The broad idea is that if you put perpendicular electric and magnetic fields on a sample, the charge carriers will be accelerated parallel to the electric field, but then also perpendicular to both the newly-acquired velocity $v$ and the magnetic field $B$.  This extra transverse curving results in a side-to-side voltage drop across the sample, and its sign depends on that of the charge carriers.

And yet various materials have significant hole and electron transport at the same time. The issue here is thinking in terms of simple bonds, not band structures.  Electrons moving in the conduction band have nothing to do with holes moving in the valence band.

For a strongly dopped semiconductors, we mai neglect the current of the minority carrier but this is still an additive conponent to the current of the dominant carrier. The sign of the Hall effect depends on both concentrations and mobilities of the carriers. In intrinsic semiconductors the sign is usually negative due to higher mobility of the conduction electrons but both carriers participate in conduction.

Sure. Just like electrolytes also have both positive and negative charge carriers. You don’t double count one as the other, and you can measure which is which with Hall measurements.

There is a problem of naming.

Electron current counts the free electrons in conductive band only as they can roam "freely" and sometimes they recombine with a hole or form hole-free electron pair.
Hole current count electrons as well but only those that leave another hole behind and recombine with the existing one.

Electron-current electrons do cover quite long distances over the crystal while hole-current electrons do short-distance jumps from localized atom to localised cation nearby (few atomic distances).
If you have crystal with a hole near anode and free electron near cathode, the bound electron close to anode will jump closer to the anode in the hole, apparently moving the hole cathode-ways. Then another electron jumps... The free electron close to cathode "freely" roams towards anode and recombine with the hole. The net change is 0 but the current counts 1e - one electron flying from cathode (until recombination) and one chain of jumps from the recombination place to the anode.
In your example you have "closed system" of an atom and cation. Jumping one electron changes the cation to atom and atom to cation. There is no free electron to be accounted, only the apparent hole jump.
Or you take it as three stages:

Hole-electron formation (there are 2 cations and one electron, net charge +1, charge transfer 0)
Electron transfer (still 2 cations and one electron, net charge +1, charge transfer 1e)
Hole-electron recombination (one cation, one atom. net charge +1, charge transfer 0)

The only reason for having electron current and hole current is to distinguish between fast and easy conducting free electrons in conductive band from slow bound electrons in valence band. From outer view they appear as fast free electrons and slow holes.
You either count all electrons (fast and slow) or count fast electrons and add holes (slow electrons). If hole (apparently) moves, it means slow electron (actually) move there the other way.

It is interesting to know that such a question is asked even now - in modern era.
It is a classical question in electrochemistry, where it was solved by Hittorff.
According to his solution, positive and negatively charged species present in an electricity conducting medium, an ionic conductor, as it is called in electrochemistry, move in opposite directions under the influence of an electric field, with different speeds, which amounts to conduction of electric current through the medium.
The sum of the currents carried by both types of species is equal to the current passing through the medium.
Therefore, each type of species carries a fraction of the current passing through the medium, and is called the transport number of the species (t+ and t-)
So, (t+ + t-) = 1.
This answers your question as to why it is not twice the current carried by a positive or negative species.
That said, I must add the following.
Hittorff solution is not correct, it is erroneous.
That is because,Hittorff solution violates the fundamental law of chemistry, viz , one equivalent of any species combines with one equivalent of any other species leading to the occurrence of one equivalent of a reaction. This is a different form of statement of the fundamental
law, namely,'The law of stoichiometry', which in turn is a form of statement symmetry, and therefore, is a fundamental law of nature.
